# Expandable list VS Swipe List (fast vs congested)

Tags: android, lists

So I have an application in which you have 2 different lists.

1. The songs that you have downloaded from others
2. The songs present on your device

Currently you ca switch between the lists using expandable lists, like this :
**Viewing the downloads**

[image]

**Viewing the songs on disk/device library**

[image]

Now my UX guy is arguing that this looks congested as there are 4 things to click on (downloads/uploads included).
A possible option is to make a new swipe list adjacent to Downloads and display the device library there. But in my opinion swiping back and forth will be slower for the user than this.
Who should I go about designing the views ?
P.S I cant merge both lists, goes against the idea of the app

> **EDIT** (MyLibrary) = (Total songs) - (songs downloaded using this app)

Comment: Red bar at the bottom, what are those buttons?

Comment: Those are the android hardware buttons for back, home etc

Comment: personally, apple UI/UX > android :)

Comment: Does someone need to see the upload/download queue from this screen?

Comment: "The songs present on your device" for example the ones that have been uploaded  by usb with a computer or in a SD card?

Comment: @rewobs yes, check edit :)

Comment: @DarrylGodden Well this is the only place right now where you can check out the ongoing uploads and downloads. In downloads list you can also play songs.

Comment: @Dexter I agree with your ux partner, I have added my answer with several other reasons to add an adjacent tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll totally agree with your co-worker and here I'll explain you why:

- **Inside your Downloads tab you should have just downloaded music**. If you want to add also music that has been introduced in the device
  by other means (usb, sd carc,etc), the "Downloads" tab is not an
  appropiate title, it's inconsistent.
- **Expandable lists are very close to each other**, so the probability
  of users miss-tapping and expanding the list which they don't want expand is higher than I'd accept.
- I agree with your UX guy that **there are too many "clutched options"** in relation with the functionality that it presents.

By adding an adjacent tab you'll gain:

- More vertical space for the content of each tab
- Cleaner interface
- Decrease miss-tapping
- Better affordance (users can guess what it's going to be inside each tab before they open it)
- It'll not be "slower", but "faster"! If the user is positioned in the upload tab, they would have to switch to the Downloads tab and then open/close the expandable list with the chance of miss-taping and doubling the number of actions needed, so user will need at least 2 actions as minimum + possible misstapping to get where they want.
  With the adjacent tab instead, they maximum number of actions needed is 1 (for the switch or the tap on the Tab) and the chance of miss-tapping is way lower.

Comment: Ok, what if I merged both lists into 1, with a simple divider separating the content ?

Comment: @Dexter I don't get your idea, if you merge both lists why would you need a divider?

Comment: to separate the songs that were downloaded from the disk songs.

Comment: @Dexter If you mean to merged the least and give the option of filtering the elemenst of each one by clicking in that divider? If that's the case I wouldn't agree because there won't be a clear sign for the user when the content is not filtered.
In the case you just meant to used a vertical divider as in Darryl answer I think it would be better than your current approach but it will only fix the miss-tapping problems but not the others.
If you meant anything else, please add an image/mockup of the idea in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you? Merging the two lines into one, but not sacrificing too much space?

[image: UI Suggestion]

Comment: well this does reduce one tab, if I decide to go ahead with separate lists, Ill consider this :)